# decryption while fetching data from database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working on Spring MVC project with Hibernate. I have an table where some columns having encrypted data. Whenever I want to fetch data (unique result or list) I have to loop over the data and perform decryption logic then again set into models/entity.

Currently we are doing like :

```
            query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT C.* FROM CITY C");
            query.addEntity(City.class);                
            List<City> list = query.list();
            for (City city : list)
            {
                city.setName(AESHelper.decrypt(city.getName(), "key"));
            }
```

can we have something in Hibernate by using we can apply such logic while hibernate is transforming data into entity, can we use `ResultTransformer` for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ResultTransformer without doubt. But, if you have a lot of columns/entities which requires this then use [Hibernate Interceptors](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html).

In your example annotate `name` with custom annotation like below

```
City {
 @CustomAnnotation(decrypt = true) 
 private String name;
..
}
```

Within the interceptor when ever data is loaded, check the entities property for this custom annotation. If it is set to true then decrypt it.

This approach is non intrusive.

[Example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/)

Update: ResultTransformer

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT name from City where name like 'xxyy'")
        .setResultTransformer(new ResultTransformer(){
   Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases){
       // assign each tuple value to your object and return
   }

})
```

Comment: I have only one column in my case. Can you show how can it be done using `ResultTransformer`.

Comment: @Amogh I think the resultTransformer returns nonMangedEntity bean, is that fine with you?

Comment: Yes, I will make an DTO class.